# How to Pause/Stop the media player from a different activity?

Tags: android

I have declared a media player variable in MediaPActivity activity and then want to pause or stop it in a Second activity. I have declared intent in the Second class but when i try to the mediplayer on click of btn1 in MediaPActivity, the mediaplayer in the Second activity is not paused/stopped. What is wrong with the below given piece of code ?

```
   public class MediaPActivity extends Activity {
Button btn, btn1;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
    btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(MediaPActivity.this, Second.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
    btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(MediaPActivity.this, Second.class);
            i.setAction(Second.ACTION_PAUSE);
            }
    });
}
```

}

Second Activity:

```
      public class Second extends Activity {
Button btnplay, btnpause;
MediaPlayer player;
public static final String ACTION_PLAY = "com.synapse.test.PLAY";
public static final String ACTION_PAUSE = "com.synapse.test.PAUSE";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.second);

    btnplay = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btnpause = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    player = new MediaPlayer();
    player = MediaPlayer.create(Second.this, R.raw.testsong_20_sec);
    btnplay.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            player.start();
        }
    });
    btnpause.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            player.pause();
        }
    });
}
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    if(intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_PLAY)){
                player.start();
        }
    else if(intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_PAUSE)){
                player.pause();
            }
        }
```

}

```
Manifest File:

  <activity
        android:name=".MediaPActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
       </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Second" android:launchMode="singleTop" />
```

Comment: what do you mean by "does not work"? Doesn't show up? please post also the output of LogCat

Comment: let me get this correct, when you try to launch the second activity by clicking `btn`, the second activity comes in front, right? what do you want next?

Comment: why don't you use service class for playing and pausing media player ?

Answer (score 0):

make the MediaPlayer object [Static](http://www.javatutorialhub.com/java-static-variable-methods.html).
Static variables are accessible from different classes, and are only initialized once.

Answer (score 0):

You doesn't call `startActivity()` inside your btn1.ClickListener. 
As your Activity is SingleTop it should then trigger `onNewIntent`

Comment: But i don't want to move to the Second Activity.

Comment: First i go to SecondActivity after clicking btn and after coming the song continues to play, and when i am on MediaPActivity i want to stop the song if it is playing and without moving to Second Activity just by clicking btn1.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is add this piece of code to your intent methods:

`yourMediaPlayer.pause()`

So the whole code would be :

```
yourMediaPlayer.pause();
Intent i ...
startActivity(i);
```